# 30amp 2 breaker sub panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

Hooking up power to a shed only going to have a few receptacles and a light.
I have 30 amp power close by where I use to use for a camper it’s only run off of 120 with 3 wires my question is can I use that for a 30amp subpanel with 2 breakers I was told I can jump off the other leg in the panel to make the other bus bar hot for 120v going to be useing a 20amp breaker for receptacles and a 15 for the light

Comment: Are you decommissioning the RV receptacle, or...?

Comment: Yes disconnecting the Rv receptacle just going to use that 30 amp 120 to feed 30 amp sub panel for 120v

Comment: Also, have you already laid the cable to the shed, or are you still planning this out?

Comment: The wire is already there  it’s a 10/2  wire

Comment: So there's a 10/2 already run from the RV receptacle to the shed?

Comment: I got 10/2 run to a rv plug I’m not longer useing that so I’m wanting to do away with the 30amp receptacle for the rv and use that 10/2 wire to hook inside the shed with a 30amp subpanel to just use it for in the shed for a few receptacle and a light going to use a 20amp breaker for receptacle and a 15 amp breaker for light. What I was wanting to know is being that the 10/2 wire only has one hot leg can I jump the hot over on the bus bar in the 30 amp sub panel to give me a 120volts on the other side so I can use 2 breakers in the sub panel

Comment: Is the RV receptacle at the shed, or at the house?

Comment: Where the shed is going to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 2-space panel as it is.  Just split the hot so it connects to both lugs. However you must use a 2-pole breaker, or handle-tie all the breakers so they throw together.  Why?  You need a disconnect switch, and that's it!  And it must be 1 throw action.

One of our crusades around here is to convince people that you are better off with a LARGE service panel, in terms of the number of spaces.  That is to say, 2-space panel considered bad; 18-space panel considered good.  Why? Physical expansion room.  The likeliest thing that will happen to you is that you will run out of breaker spaces.  This is an expensive and awkward problem, and **it is easily avoided by getting an excessively large panel (for right now)**.

Saving money is awesome. We'll help you do that here.  But the message for now is, a baby panel is the worst possible place you could try to save money! **There's very little money to be saved** (I joke about "a few latté's" but it's true), and so much frustration and cost when you hit the wall later.

So take back the 2-space and get at least a 12-space.

I'll even say to get a panel with a "main breaker".  That becomes your mandatory disconnect switch. The cheapest way to get a 30A disconnect switch is to get a panel with a main breaker >= 30A. (Since you're only using it as a disconnect switch, size does not matter).

In the future if  you make your supply wire bigger, it just hooks up to the main-breaker panel. No need for an upgrade!

### Hooking up to the disconnect switch

If you got a main-breaker panel, you take your 30A 120V "Hot" wire and split it.  That is, you put two 6" pigtails on the 2 hot inputs of the main breaker, and wire-nut that to your 30A input (you'll need a big blue or tan wire nut).   Now you can fit breakers normally.

NO MWBCs (shared neutral) circuits!  (if you don't know what that is, don't worry about it).

If you got a main-lug (no main breaker) panel, then you'll have to backfeed it.  (i.e. bring power "in" the normal "out" of a breaker).  Backfeed breakers require bolt-down kits, and bolt-down kits require 2-pole breakers.  So split the power to feed both "hots" of the 2-pole breaker.  This can't be a $80 GFCI breaker, you can't backfeed a GFCI!

In a pinch, you could use something like a quadplex breaker. Bolt down the quadplex.  Then backfeed with the two inner (say: 30A) breakers and serve your loads with the two outer (say: 20A) breakers.

There is also a "Tie the buses together" cheat that can be done, where  you run a wire connecting the two main lugs.  However, this doesn't buy you anything in a 30A panel.  Having too few spaces is still a huge problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's ok to connect both hot legs to the same phase. Obviously you can't use 240 volt breakers and won't have 240v there. But it is OK to connect both bus bars to the same phase (leg).

Comment: Ok thanks just maken sure I didn’t want to buy a new wire if I already got power there from where I had my camper and don’t need that plug anymore I’m not planing on useing anything with 240 volts thanks